# Dimension of an R-Module as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $R :=\mathbb C[T]$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in the field of complex numbers $\mathbb C$, and let $M$ be the $R$-module determined by the following presentation:
$M$ is generated by elements $x$ and $y$, with relations:
                $Tx = y$ and $T^{2}x = y$.

How can I determine the dimension of $M$ as a vectorspace over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Is $M$ a module or an algebra?

Comment: $M$ is a module

Comment: What does $x^{\color{red}2}$ mean, then?

Comment: I'm sorry, the relations should be $Tx = y$ and $T^{2}x = y$, and not with $x^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $Tx=y$, $M$ is actually generated by $x$. Since $T^2x=y=Tx$, $M$ is a $R$-module generated by one element $x$ subject to the relation $(T^2-T)x=0$, so
$$M\simeq \mathbb{C}[T]/(T^2-T)\simeq \mathbb{C}[T]/(T)\times \mathbb{C}[T]/(T-1)$$
so as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space we get
$$M \simeq \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}.$$